# Merging a click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way I can merge the two?

```js
 $('.menu').click(function() {
   $('#css-menu').toggleClass('shown hidden');
 });
```

and

```js
$(function() {
  $('.menu').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

in such a workable away that when '#css-menu' = shown, '.menu' would be = active and otherwise when #css-menu is hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say w/o seeing where you register the first click handler. But if you want to listen for a click in both click handlers starting from the same time (the page load) you can most likely just merge the first into the second like:

```
$(function() {
  $('.menu').click(function() {
    $('#css-menu').toggleClass('shown hidden');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

`$(function()` is just making sure the code line `$('.menu').click(function()` is not executed as long as the DOM is not completely loaded. Otherwise it could not be able to find the `.menu` element, depending on where you include the script.

The code inside the click handler is not launched anyway as long as you don't click on the element. So it doesn't make a difference if you register two click handlers or if you just put them in one. One is better because of performance reasons of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger the two task at on click then write the two condition inside the click function and total one inside a function

something like this .

```
$(function() {  /* main function */

$('.menu').click(function(e) {   /* click event */
 e.preventDefault();    
$('#css-menu').toggleClass('shown hidden');
$(this).toggleClass('active');
});
});
```

hope it will work.